# taking a value through html and diplay it in php page

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, submit

I want the user to enter the data in text field,which will be created using html.When the user clicks on submit button,the page,whose url is mentoined int form tag will be loded.In that page,which will be in php, i want to diplay the email enterd by the user, what is the codefor this?The nvalues of the text fields are email and password respectively!

Comment: This is an Q&A site and not a canihazthecodez site. Also check out the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the method that your form uses to submit the form. This can be GET or POST, and is set by the method attribute on your form.

For a GET request you can access the variables like this:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

For a POST request you should use:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Do not forget to escape the input if you store it in a database, or escape the output if you display it to the users on your page!

Comment: @GRa Could you accept the answer that has worked for you? You can do that by checking the tick symbol next to the answer you would like to accept. This makes it easier for people reading this question to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the method you use for the form to submit you should either use:

```
echo $_POST['inputName'];
```

or

```
echo $_GET['inputName'];
```

or even (has both in them)

```
echo $_REQUEST['inputName'];
```

where `inputName` is the "name" field of your input, like:

```
<input type="text" name="inputName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_REQUEST` method to get all values passed from your HTML or any page and use that to display in PHP, pretty simple !